# Is it possible to nin filter a regex queryset?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I wrote a pymongo aggregation pipeline for my MongoDB, which not only takes a long time but also doesn't exactly return what it is supposed to. I expect the `free_id` field to be matched via regex, as it works with the `$in` command as well, but it doesn't seem to work, as this still returns documents with free_ids matching `XXX-XXX/YXYXYXYXY/.*`.

```
.aggregate([
        {"$match": {"free_id": {
            "$nin": ["XXX-XXX/YXYXYXYXY/.*"]}}},
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$free_id",
                "count": {"$sum": 1},
                "ts": {"$last": "$payload.ts"}
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "internal_id": {"$slice": [{"$split": ["$_id", '/']}, 1, 1]},
                "document_count": "$count",
                "last_ts": "$ts"
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {"$first": "$internal_id"},
                "docs": {"$sum": "$document_count"},
                "last": {"$last": "$last_ts"}
            }
        },
    ])
```

I already tried with negating a `$in` and double checked the calls etc. Theoretically I expect a similar response as I would get by using `find({"free_id": {'$not': {'$regex': "XXX-XXX/YXYXYXYXY/.*"}}})`.

Comment: You can use the same filter you are using in the `find` method - also in the `$match` stage.

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks, this actually works, even though it still takes a long time to resolve. Do you know why it doesn't work with $nin?

Comment: `$nin` is looking in a list of values, and you are trying a regex search - they are different functions altogether. Long time? It is an issue about performance. See this: [regex and index use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use).